# Google App Engine Socket TimeOut Exception

Tags: google-app-engine, socket-timeout-exception

All the servlets on App Engine are being timed Out. And they throw SocketTimeOut Exception.

Same Happens for Google App Script.

Comment: both are unrelated technologies. show proof.

Comment: We were seeing lots of timeouts on appengine this morning for a few hours on live. May be related. Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Since no information has been provided about the environment it's difficult to suggest a course of action.

However, if you're using the Python standard environment on App Engine, note that this environment has quotas on sockets depending upon your package. If you hit these then you may start to experience SocketTimeOut exceptions.